# XSLT Sorting with

Tags: xslt, sorting

I am using the Muenchian method to group data from my xml document from [Marc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by) and I am trying to sort the data within each group without much success.

I have tried the following, but no sorting is carried out:

replaced:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MemberLastName"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="MemberLastName" > 
    <xsl:sort order="ascending" /> 
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I have also tried the following, but the data is being outputted as plain text, and not sorted

```
 <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet/QueryResultData">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="MemberLastName"/>
   <xsl:sort select="MemberFirstName"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```

with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="MemberLastName"/>
```

here's my complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>      
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="/NewDataSet/QueryResultData" use="MemberReportGroup4Description" />

  <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="QueryResultData[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', MemberReportGroup4Description)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime" />
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($dateTime, 'T')" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before($date, '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($month, '/', $day, '/', $year)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="formatCourse">
    <xsl:param name="courseTitle" />
    <xsl:variable name="course" select="substring-after($courseTitle, '|')" />
    <xsl:value-of select='$course' />
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="organizationName">
    <xsl:param name="orgName" />
    <xsl:value-of select='$orgName' />
  </xsl:template> 

   <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet/QueryResultData">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="MemberLastName"/>
      <xsl:sort select="MemberFirstName"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>






  <xsl:template name="QueryResultData" match="QueryResultData">

  <style type="text/css">
th { text-align:left; font-weight:bold;}

#stores
{
font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:600px;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding: 5px;
}
#stores td, #stores th 
{
font-size:8pt;
border:1px solid #C8EAC8;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#stores th 
{
font-size:8pt;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:4px;
background-color:#339933;
color:#fff;
}
.odd 
{
color:#000;
background-color:#ECF8EC;
}
h1.store { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #000099; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:-2px;}

.CenterText { text-align:center !important; }
</style>


    <h1 class="store"> 
        <xsl:call-template name="organizationName">
          <xsl:with-param name="orgName" select="/NewDataSet/MetaData/OrganizationName" />
        </xsl:call-template>, #<xsl:value-of select="MemberReportGroup4Description"/></h1>
    <table id="stores">
      <tr class="heading">
        <th scope="col">Learner</th>
        <th scope="col">Course</th>
        <th scope="col">Enrollment Date</th>
        <th scope="col" class="CenterText">Viewed %</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', MemberReportGroup4Description)">
        <tr>
          <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="MemberLastName"/>, <xsl:value-of select="MemberFirstName"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="formatCourse">
                <xsl:with-param name="courseTitle" select="SortPrefixAndTitle" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="EnrollmentDate" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </td>
          <td class="CenterText">
            <xsl:value-of select="ViewedPercentage"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: add some input document. The one you link has not `QueryResultData` element.

Comment: I think I know the problem, but I'm not going to guess. Please, add some input.

Comment: "XSLT Sorting with" - with **what**?

Comment: I have downvoted this question and also voted to CLOSE it. The reason is that the OP has not provided any source XML and any wanted result, and any description of the desired properties of the transformation. Without this data the question doesn't define a problem.

Comment: @John, apparently my question was truncated or something else happened - but the opening paragraph explained my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change `<xsl:value-of select="MemberLastName"/>`. Instead, just put the sort element above it, just under the `for-each`:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', MemberReportGroup4Description)">
    <xsl:sort select="MemberLastName"/>
    <xsl:sort select="MemberFirstName"/>
    <tr>
      <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="MemberLastName"/>, <xsl:value-of select="MemberFirstName"/>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```