# Group By XSLT 1.0, group of groups

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I kind of need to create "group of groups" using XSLT.

Below are my XML and XSL files. I used this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by) to apply Muenchian grouping. I have tried to shorten the file and show only the required elements that represents the problem.

**XML FILE**

```
<IO_SearchShoppingFilesResult xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.IO.Shopping" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ShoppingFiles
 xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Shopping"
 xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Air">
    <a:T_ShoppingFile>
        ....
        <b:T_AirBookingItem>
            ...
            <a:LocalPaxType>ADT</a:LocalPaxType>
            ...
        </b:T_AirBookingItem>
        <b:T_AirBookingItem>
            ...
            <a:LocalPaxType>CHD</a:LocalPaxType>
            ...
        </b:T_AirBookingItem>
        <b:T_AirBookingItem>
            ...
            <a:LocalPaxType>INF</a:LocalPaxType>
            ...
        </b:T_AirBookingItem>
        ...
    </a:T_ShoppingFile>

    <a:T_ShoppingFile>
        ....
        <b:T_AirBookingItem>
            ...
            <a:LocalPaxType>ADT</a:LocalPaxType>
            ...
        </b:T_AirBookingItem>
        ...
    </a:T_ShoppingFile>
</ShoppingFiles>
</IO_SearchShoppingFilesResult>
```

**XSL FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:res="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.IO.Shopping"
xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Shopping"
xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Air"
xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
xmlns:bb="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Shopping.Views">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


<xsl:key name="travelerGroup"
    match="res:IO_SearchShoppingFilesResult/res:ShoppingFiles/a:T_ShoppingFile[position()=1]/a:AirBookings/b:T_AirBooking/b:BookingItems/b:T_AirBookingItem"
    use="b:PaxReference/a:LocalPaxType" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="PNRViewRS">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="res:IO_SearchShoppingFilesResult/res:ShoppingFiles" />
    </xsl:element>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="res:ShoppingFiles">
    <!-- For FareGroup, Traveler, Telephone, EmailAddress -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a:T_ShoppingFile" />
    ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:T_ShoppingFile">
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates
            select="a:AirBookings/b:T_AirBooking/b:BookingItems/b:T_AirBookingItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('travelerGroup', b:PaxReference/a:LocalPaxType)[1])]" />
    ...
</xsl:template>
...
<xsl:template match="b:T_AirBookingItem">
    ...
                    <!-- Line 1 -->
        <xsl:value-of
            select="count(key('travelerGroup', b:PaxReference/a:LocalPaxType))" />  
    ...

</xsl:template>
```

As one can see, I have applied `key` on `<b:T_AirBookingItem>`. And multiple `<b:T_AirBookingItem>` are present in multiple `<a:T_ShoppingFile>`.

Now, I want to handle each `<a:T_ShoppingFile>` separately and then apply grouping on all the `<b:T_AirBookingItem>` present in it. What happens here in this code is that all the `<b:T_AirBookingItem>` of all the `<a:T_ShoppingFile>` are grouped all together at a time.

Line 1 shows one of the result of this transformation. It should show total number of `<b:T_AirBookingItem>` of a particular `<a:LocalPaxType>` (say ADT) **for a single `<a:T_ShoppingFile>`**. However, it considers all the `<b:T_AirBookingItem>` in the whole of XML instead.

So where I should get "1" number of ADTs, I am getting "2".

How do I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you want to make use of a compound key, consisting of more than one element. In this case you are gouping by **a:T_ShoppingFile** and **a:LocalPaxType**, so you probably need something like this

```
<xsl:key 
   name="item" 
   match="b:T_AirBookingItem" 
   use="concat(generate-id(..) , '|', a:LocalPaxType)" />
```

Then, for each **a:T_ShoppingFile** to get the unique **a:LocalPaxType** records, you just do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
  select="b:T_AirBookingItem[generate-id() 
    = generate-id(key('item', concat(generate-id(..) , '|', a:LocalPaxType))[1])]" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:res="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.IO.Shopping" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Shopping" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Air" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:bb="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trevoo.WS.Entities.Shopping.Views" exclude-result-prefixes="res a b c bb">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="item" match="b:T_AirBookingItem" use="concat(generate-id(..) , '|', a:LocalPaxType)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:T_ShoppingFile"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a:T_ShoppingFile">
      <file number="{position()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="b:T_AirBookingItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item', concat(generate-id(..) , '|', a:LocalPaxType))[1])]"/>
      </file>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="b:T_AirBookingItem">
      <result>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(a:LocalPaxType, ' * ', count(key('item', concat(generate-id(..) , '|', a:LocalPaxType))), '&#13;')"/>
      </result>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<file number="1">
   <result>ADT * 1</result>
   <result>CHD * 1</result>
   <result>INF * 1</result>
</file>
<file number="2">
   <result>ADT * 1</result>
</file>
```

Obviously, this shows results for all **a:T_ShoppingFile** and **a:LocalPaxType**. If you wanted to restrict to a particular **a:LocalPaxType** you could do something like this (although you would probably want to parameterise the value, rather than hard-code **ADT**

```
   <xsl:template match="a:T_ShoppingFile">
      <file number="{position()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="count(key('item', concat(generate-id() , '|', 'ADT')))" />
      </file>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Exact solution to my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: The idea of using 'compound key' is great!!

Comment: Do ensure that the delimited that joins the two parts (the bar | in this case) does not occur in either of the two parts of the key.