# XSLT: How to process all elements with a child of the same value

Tags: xslt

Simply put I have XML similar to (trimmed a lot):

```
<Event>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>#ID</Name>
    <Value>3</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>AMT</Name>
    <Value>911</Value>
  </Parameter>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>#ID</Name>
    <Value>3</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>AMT</Name>
    <Value>10</Value>
  </Parameter>
</Event>
<Event>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>#ID</Name>
    <Value>4</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>AMT</Name>
    <Value>11</Value>
  </Parameter>
</Event>
```

From this I want to process all Event elements that have the same "Value" for the Parameter that has a Name of "#ID". So the sample output might be:

```
<Result>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <AMT>10</AMT>
  <AMT>11</AMT>
<Result>
<Result>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <AMT>11</AMT>
<Result>
```

It is a little more complicated than that but hopefully an answer to this will be sufficient to get me unstuck. My main problem is I don't know how to collect and process together all of the Event elements that have the same Value in a Parameter with a Name of #ID.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to merge the parameter values by #ID? And shouldn't the example output `<AMT>10</AMT><AMT>911</AMT>` for `#ID=3`?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT2.0? This has the helpful **xsl:for-each-group** element specifically for grouping like this.

Comment: Yes to both. Sorry, was a typo on the 911 part of it, I was posting on a machine over RDP and it was freezing a lot.

Comment: Tim C, I'm looking into:for-each-group right now. Strange that it hasn't appeared on w3schools yet.

Comment: http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314 provides a good overview of `<xsl:for-each-group>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using XSLT2.0, you can use **xsl:for-each-group** to group your event elements by their ID in the parameter element

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Event" group-by="Parameter[Name='#ID']/Value">
```

I am not sure if you wanted to total the "AMT" elements, or output them individually, but to output them individually, you would do this (with a separate matching template to output them)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/Parameter[Name='AMT']"/>
```

And to total them up you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Parameter[Name='AMT']/Value)"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Event" group-by="Parameter[Name='#ID']/Value">
         <Result>
            <ID>
               <!-- <xsl:value-of select="Parameter[Name='#ID']/Value"/> -->
               <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            </ID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/Parameter[Name='AMT']"/>
            <TOTAL_AMT>
               <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Parameter[Name='AMT']/Value)"/>
            </TOTAL_AMT>
         </Result>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Parameter[Name='AMT']">
      <AMT>
         <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
      </AMT>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<Events>
   <Event>
      <Parameter>
         <Name>#ID</Name>
         <Value>3</Value>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter>
         <Name>AMT</Name>
         <Value>911</Value>
      </Parameter>
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <Parameter>
         <Name>#ID</Name>
         <Value>3</Value>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter>
         <Name>AMT</Name>
         <Value>10</Value>
      </Parameter>
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <Parameter>
         <Name>#ID</Name>
         <Value>4</Value>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter>
         <Name>AMT</Name>
         <Value>11</Value>
      </Parameter>
   </Event>
</Events>
```

The following is output

```
<Result>
   <ID>3</ID>
   <AMT>911</AMT>
   <AMT>10</AMT>
   <TOTAL_AMT>921</TOTAL_AMT>
</Result>
<Result>
   <ID>4</ID>
   <AMT>11</AMT>
   <TOTAL_AMT>11</TOTAL_AMT>
</Result>
```

Comment: Or even simpler `<ID><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /></ID>`

Comment: Damn, it appears I'm not using XSLT 2.0. It's a Java program and I'm using xalan, just assumed it would be 2.0 but "line 16: Unsupported XSL element 'for-each-group" says otherwise. I'm going to go find an XSLT 2.0 compliant library. After that I'm sure the above is exaclty what I need.

Comment: If you do end up being restricted to XSLT 1.0, read up on a technique called "Muenchian Grouping" as that will be your friend here.

Comment: To add to what @TimC said: [XSLT 1.0 Group By](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by#1903953)

Comment: Thanks. Already found another post by Tim C on Muenchian Grouping. Going to try my hardest to upgrade now. Turns out I'm not using xalan, I'm using dom4j, I have a feeling that is a side-effect of another dependency.

Comment: Just to update, your response @TimC was awesome. I've started using Saxon and it is working. My solution is branching considerably from what you provided but the information you all gave me was great.