# XSL Grouping and sub grouping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I found this post on Muenchian grouping [XSLT 1.0 Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by), and got part way with what I want to do, but I can't work out how to group my sub-nodes.

My XML looks a little like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
   <Vehicle>
     <ManufacturerId>53</ManufacturerId>
     <ManufacturerName>VAUXHALL</ManufacturerName>
     <Model>Corsa</Model>
   </vehicle>
   <Vehicle>
     <ManufacturerId>53</ManufacturerId>
     <ManufacturerName>VAUXHALL</ManufacturerName>
     <Model>Astra</Model>
   </vehicle>
   <Vehicle>
     <ManufacturerId>53</ManufacturerId>
     <ManufacturerName>VAUXHALL</ManufacturerName>
     <Model>Corsa</Model>
   </vehicle>
   <Vehicle>
     <ManufacturerId>54</ManufacturerId>
     <ManufacturerName>FORD</ManufacturerName>
     <Model>KA</Model>
   </vehicle>
   <Vehicle>
     <ManufacturerId>54</ManufacturerId>
     <ManufacturerName>FORD</ManufacturerName>
     <Model>Focus</Model>
   </vehicle>
   <Vehicle>
     <ManufacturerId>54</ManufacturerId>
     <ManufacturerName>FORD</ManufacturerName>
     <Model>KA</Model>
   </vehicle>
   <Vehicle>
     <ManufacturerId>55</ManufacturerId>
     <ManufacturerName>CITROEN</ManufacturerName>
     <Model>C4</Model>
   </vehicle>
<NewDataSet>
```

This is the code I have thus far

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="groups" match="/NewDataSet/Vehicle" use="ManufacturerName" />
   <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Vehicle[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', ManufacturerName)[1])]"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Vehicle">
     <div class="makeLnk">
     <a href="/stocklist/?ManufacturerId={ManufacturerId}"><xsl:value-of select="ManufacturerName"/></a>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', ManufacturerName)">
      <div class="modelLnk"><xsl:value-of select="Model"/></div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This groups together the ManufacturerNames and lists all the models under. But I would now like to group the models as well, thus removing duplicate names. But can't work out the syntax.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second key composed of the `ManufacturerName` of the `Vehicle` and the value of the `Model`:

```
<xsl:key name="model" match="Vehicle/Model" use="concat(../ManufacturerName, '|', .)"/>
```

then replace

```
   <xsl:template match="Vehicle">
     <div class="makeLnk">
     <a href="/stocklist/?ManufacturerId={ManufacturerId}"><xsl:value-of select="ManufacturerName"/></a>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', ManufacturerName)">
      <div class="modelLnk"><xsl:value-of select="Model"/></div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
   </xsl:template>
```

with

```
   <xsl:template match="Vehicle">
     <div class="makeLnk">
     <a href="/stocklist/?ManufacturerId={ManufacturerId}"><xsl:value-of select="ManufacturerName"/></a>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', ManufacturerName)/Model[generate-id() = 
  generate-id(key('model', concat(../ManufacturerName, '|', .))[1])]">
      <div class="modelLnk"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
   </xsl:template>
```