# Merging set of elements based on a common attribute in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I m working with XSLT1.0 . My requirement is to merge set of elements based on a common attribute.
I ve an xml which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Catalog>
    <product>
        <productId>S100</productId>
        <name>RNKC</name>
        <category>books</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>S100</productId>
        <name>RNKC</name>
        <category>CD</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>S200</productId>
        <name>ISDR</name>
        <category>eBook</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>S200</productId>
        <name>ISDR</name>
        <category>books</category>
    </product>
</Catalog>
```

I want the output XML as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Catalog>
    <product>
        <productId>S100</productId>
        <name>RNKC</name>
        <category>books,CD</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>S200</productId>
        <name>RNKC</name>
        <category>eBook,books</category>
    </product>
</Catalog>
```

Have tried using  but couldnt achieve the correct output. Pls let me know if this kind of transformation is possible and how it can be done.
Appreciate your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by seems to be similar.

Comment: Minor design point, but I wouldn't concatenate values into a single element like this. You're far better off having multiple `category` elements, preferably with a parent `categories` element. It'll make further processing/querying much easier, if you need them comma separated for any reason, this can be done at the point where the data's used.

Comment: @halfbit - Thanks for pointing me to Muenchian grouping!

Comment: @Flynn1179 - Yes, but I m trying to insert this data into DB where ProductId would be the key. So the required grouping! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the other topic halfbit linked to, you need to use a key in order to (1) select distinct products (aka the Muenchian method) and (2) collect the values from the related group.

Here's a little more readable (IMHO) version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="sameProduct" match="product" use="productId" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- SELECT ONLY THE FIRST PRODUCT IN EACH GROUP -->
<xsl:for-each select="Catalog/product[generate-id() = generate-id(key('sameProduct', productId)[1])]">
<product>
    <productId><xsl:value-of select="productId"/></productId>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
    <category>
        <!-- GET THE VALUES FROM ALL MEMBERS OF THE GROUP -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('sameProduct', productId)">
            <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </category>
</product>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your processor is EXSLT capable, you can use the set:distinct() function instead of the Muenchian grouping.

Comment: Thanks , this example was very helpful! Along with the explanation for Muenchian grouping here http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html