# How to add additional tables in XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to create more than one table in my document. This is the current XSLT code im using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2 align="center">UFC Fighter Roster</h2>
<table border="0" align="left" width="20%" >
  <th>Heavyweight</th>
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
      </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="roster/cd">
    <xsl:if test="weight=180">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="rank"/></td>
      </tr>
</table>


    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using this table to pull fighters at weight=180, if I wanted to produce a table on the same page that represents the fighters whose weight=170 how do I go about it because everytime i try using the same code but a different weight figure it doesnt work?

Here is a version of my XML that I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<roster>
    <cd>
        <title>Cain Velasquez</title>
        <rank>1st</rank>
        <weight>180</weight>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Fabricio Werdum</title>
        <rank>2nd</rank>
        <weight>180</weight>

    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Junior Dos Santos</title>
        <rank>3rd</rank>
        <weight>180</weight>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Travis Browne</title>
        <rank>4th</rank>
        <weight>180</weight>

    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Antonio Silva</title>
        <rank>5th</rank>
        <weight>180</weight>

    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Jon Jones</title>
        <rank>1st</rank>
        <weight>170</weight>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Alexander Guftasson</title>
        <rank>2nd</rank>
        <weight>170</weight>

    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Rashad Evans</title>
        <rank>3rd</rank>
        <weight>170</weight>

    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Glover Teixiera</title>
        <rank>4th</rank>
        <weight>170</weight>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Shogun Rua</title>
        <rank>5th</rank>
        <weight>170</weight>
    </cd>

</catalog>
```

Comment: The value you use depends on the contents of a `<weight>` element in your *source* document. Please edit your question and add your XML source. Also, fix your XSL because it's not well formed (there are two closing `</table>` tags, an extra closing angle bracket, at least).

Comment: I've added the XML source and fixed the XSL @helderdarocha

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using this table to pull fighters at weight=180, if I wanted to
>   produce a table on the same page that represents the fighters whose
>   weight=170 how do I go about it

You should use a **key** instead of trying to do this with `xsl:if`.

---

### Edit

For example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="cd-by-weight" match="cd" use="weight" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Heavyweight</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Rank</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('cd-by-weight', 180)">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="rank"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Less Heavyweight</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Rank</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('cd-by-weight', 170)">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="rank"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming the source document always contains fighters of both weights. Note that the duplication of code could be eliminated by calling a named template with the weight as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Check [XSLT 1.0 Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by)

In XSL 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2 align="center">UFC Fighter Roster</h2>

                <xsl:for-each-group select="roster/cd" group-by="weight">
                   <table border="0" align="left" width="20%" >
                        <th>Heavyweight</th>
                        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Rank</th>
                        </tr>
                       <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <tr>
                                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title/node()"/></td>
                                    <td><xsl:value-of select="rank/node()"/></td>
                         </tr>
                          </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>  
                </xsl:for-each-group>


            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to be modular, you can do it as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2 align="center">UFC Fighter Roster</h2>
            <xsl:call-template name="table">
                <xsl:with-param name="title">Heavyweight</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="w" select="180"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="table">
                <xsl:with-param name="title">weight (170)</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="w" select="170"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="table">
    <xsl:param name="w"/>
    <xsl:param name="title"/>
    <table border="0" align="left" width="20%" >
        <th><xsl:value-of select="$title"/></th>
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/cd[weight=$w]"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="rank"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For XSLT2.0 grouping is a good alternative, and if you want specific value then use current-group-key():

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()[current-grouping-key() = ('170','180')]">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title/node()"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="rank/node()"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope it will help.
regards,
yann