# XSLT 1.0 Group by + Concat

Tags: xslt, group-by, concatenation, xslt-1.0

i have the following XML:

**Source:**

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <Telephone>340000000000000000</Telephone>
    <ID>154815</ID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <Telephone>340000000000000000</Telephone>
    <ID>154814</ID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <Telephone>340000000000000001</Telephone>
    <ID>154814</ID>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

I need:

1. group by all ID
2. concat Telephone in group

**Result:**

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <Telephone>340000000000000000</Telephone>
    <ID>154815</ID>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <Telephone>340000000000000000;340000000000000001</Telephone>
    <ID>154814</ID>
  </Order>

</Orders>
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by

Answer (score 0):

Done:
(Some Tips please :))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/Orders">
    
      <Orders>
        <!--GROUP BY -->
        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Order[not(preceding-sibling::Order/ID = ID)]/ID" />

      </Orders>
    

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="ID" >
    <Order>

      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </ID>
      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../Telephone"/>
   
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>


  <!--STRING_AGG -->

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="record-by-entry" match="Order" use="ID" />


  <xsl:template match="Telephone">
    
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('record-by-entry', ../ID)" >
        <xsl:value-of select="Telephone" />
        <!--<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">-->
          <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        
        <!--</xsl:if>-->
      </xsl:for-each>
      
     
    
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tip: this is not a good solution. Read about Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html.

Comment: Use the key you have declared so instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="Order[not(preceding-sibling::Order/ID = ID)]/ID"/>` use `<xsl:apply-templates select="Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('record-by-entry', ID)[1])]"/>`. Also I am not sure why you match on `ID` but not on `Order`, should be easier to match e.g. `<xsl:template match="Order"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="ID"/><Telephone><xsl:apply-templates select="key('record-by-entry', ID)/Telephone"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`

Comment: And then just `<xsl:template match="Telephone"><xsl:if test="position() > 1">;</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>`